# How to replace response code sent to client when using Apache httpd to reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, http, mod-proxy

I have a database that accepts HTTP POST requests with JSON payloads and correctly returns an HTTP 201 Created status response and some JSON content.

Garmin has a service that will POST JSON to a provided URL but only considers an HTTP 200 OK response as a success. Anything else it considers an error which prompts retries at a decreasing pace until it gives up.

Garmin is refusing to fix their code so I'm left to implement a workaround.

I am already using Apache to proxy requests to applications and databases in our environment and thought there must surely be a way to proxy these requests, check if the response from the DB was a 201 Created and if so, replace it with 200 OK on the way back to Garmin.

I have read the entire mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http, mod_header, and mod_rewrite documentation pages and hunted through various related questions, answers, and search results. The closest I have gotten is [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083481/how-can-i-replace-apache-http-code-404-to-200/15088830#15088830) making use of the Redirect directive and an empty error page. But the code I am replacing is actually a success code so I cannot use the ErrorDocument directive with it.

The ideal solution should work within a `<Location>` context containing ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives. It should only replace a 201 response from the back-end HTTP DB with a 200 response and same content. It should not alter any other responses.

If no solutions using Apache directives are forthcoming, I would also welcome alternative solutions to accomplish the same goal using other open source software.

Thank you for your help!